# Using a DisplayTemplate (with DisplayFor) for each item in a collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, display-templates

I have created a DisplayTemplate for a `Comment` class, and placed it inside `Comment/DisplayTemplates/Comment.cshtml`.

`Comment.cshtml` is properly typed:

```
@model Comment
```

Then, I have a partial view that takes an `IEnumerable<Comment>` for model. In there I loop through the collection and would like to use the DisplayTemplate for the `Comment` class. The view, in its integrity:

```
@model IEnumerable<Comment>

@foreach (var comment in Model.Where(c => c.Parent == null)) { 
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => comment)
}
```

However, I get an error on the `Html.DisplayFor` line:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'.

How can I invoke the DisplayTemplate for each item in the `foreach` loop?

Comment: If you change "model" to something like "myCommentModel" in your lambda expression does it work?

Comment: Thanks Joe, but no, it doesn't. Why would it? What was your rationale behind it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Instead of having a view that take an `IEnumerable<Comment>` and that all it does is loop through the collection and call the proper display template simply:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Comments)
```

where the Comments property is an `IEnumerable<Comment>` which will automatically do the looping and render the `Comment.cshtml` display template for each item of this collection.

Or if you really need such a view (don't know why) you could simply:

```
@model IEnumerable<Comment>
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

As far as the `Where` clause you are using in there you should simply remove it and delegate this task to the controller. It's the controller's responsibility to prepare the view model, not the view performing such tasks.

Comment: Hah! Brilliant! I didn't know `DisplayFor` would automatically loop. Got rid of the view too, of course. Thanks! (I agree about the `Where` clause, I got lazy there for a minute ;)

Comment: @Sergi Papaseit, that's why everytime I see someone writing a loop in a view I always suggest him using templates.

Comment: Well, I certainly won't forget this one any more :)

Comment: @DarinDimitrov do you have any idea why this is not working in my case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678802/why-is-my-displayfor-not-looping-through-my-ienumerabledatetime

Comment: "Or if you really need such a view (don't know why)". `DisplayFor` can render the list, but it won't render a table.

Answer (score 13):

While the accepted answer works well most of the time, there are other cases in which we need to be aware of the element's index when rendering (i.e. add custom javascript that generates references to each element based on their index).

In that case, DisplayFor can still be used within the loop like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Comment>

@for (int index = 0; index < Model.Count(); index++)
{
     @Html.DisplayFor(model => model[index])
}
```

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` does not support implicit indexing with `[i]`. Logically then, you would try to use `model.ElementAt(i)` but then you get an error, so you can only do this by using `Comment[]` as the model type or `model.ToArray()[i]`