# Why is my DisplayFor not looping through my IEnumerable<DateTime>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view

I have this line in my view

```
@(Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DaysOfWeek, "_CourseTableDayOfWeek"))
```

where `m.DaysOfWeek` is a `IEnumerable<DateTime>`.

There is the content of _CourseTableDayOfWeek.cshtml:

```
@model DateTime
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CourseTableDayOfWeek";
}
<th>
    @System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[(int) Model.DayOfWeek]
    <span class="dateString">Model.ToString("G")</span>
</th>
```

And I get the following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '`` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.DateTime] ``', but this dictionary requires a model item of type '`System.DateTime`'.

If I refer to the following post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5652524/277067

The `DisplayFor` should be looping through the IEnumerable and display the template for each item, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's not looping because you have specified a name for the display template as second argument of the `DisplayFor` helper (`_CourseTableDayOfWeek`).

It loops only when you rely on conventions i.e.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DaysOfWeek)
```

and then inside `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/DateTime.cshtml`:

```
@model DateTime
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CourseTableDayOfWeek";
}
<th>
    @System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DayNames[(int) Model.DayOfWeek]
    <span class="dateString">Model.ToString("G")</span>
</th>
```

Once you specify a custom name for the display template (either as second argument of the DisplayFor helper or as `[UIHint]` attribute) it will no longer loop for collection properties and the template will simply be passed the `IEnumerable<T>` as model.

It's confusing but that's how it is. I don't like it either.

Comment: Ditto.  Another aspect of these helpers that was difficult to debug and not at all clear.

Comment: I just fell into the same trap.  This seems totally counter-intuitive to me.  I hope this changes with MVC 4.

Comment: @JohnH It hasn't changed. Still works this way in MVC 5.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug.  Html Helper classes are easy to extend, although after looking at the MVC source, looking for the bug, I gave up and just leveraged the premise that templates work for an individual item, so I wrote an HtmlHelper extension that wraps it for you.  I took out the lambda expression for my own simplicity, but you can easily go back to that.  This example is just for a list of strings.

```
    public static class DisplayTextListExtension
{
    public static MvcHtmlString DisplayForList<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, IEnumerable<string> model, string templateName)
    {
        var tempResult = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            tempResult.Append(html.DisplayFor(m => item, templateName));
        }

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(tempResult.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then the actual usage looks like:

```
                                @Html.DisplayForList(Model.Organizations, "infoBtn")
```

Answer (score 0):

A minor tweak to allow this to [Dan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19735790/7851470) to be a little more generic:

```
public static class DisplayTextListExtension
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString DisplayForList<TModel, 
EModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, IEnumerable<EModel> model, string templateName)
        {
            var tempResult = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var item in model)
            {
                tempResult.Append(html.DisplayFor(m => item, templateName));
            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(tempResult.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `FilterUIHint` instead of the regular `UIHint`, on the `IEnumerable<T>` property.

```
public class MyModel
{
    [FilterUIHint("_CourseTableDayOfWeek")]
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> DaysOfWeek { get; set; }
}
```

No need for anything else.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DaysOfWeek)
```

This now displays an `"_CourseTableDayOfWeek"` EditorTemplate for each `DateTime` in `DaysOfWeek`.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. It just ignored the FilterUIHint, like there was no annotation. Also you used DisplayFor but said EditorTemplate for each; was that a mistake or on purpose?