# Html.DisplayForModel throwing InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My view is

```
@model List<string>
...
@Html.DisplayForModel("Name")
...
```

My "Name" display template is

```
@model string
<span>@Model</span>
```

This isn't working, I am getting:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[string]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'string'`

Anything wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Possible reason: Model == null

Answer (score 2):

The model of your first list is of type `List<string>` and you pass this model to the display template. But the display template requires a model of type `string`. Your display template should also expect a list of strings:

```
@model List<string>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
   <span>@item</span>
}
```

Comment: I thought DisplayFor() can be used to display the list of items in the model as answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261590/mvc-razor-foreach

Comment: @santhudr what if you change the model type of the view to `IEnumerable<string>` and then call it with `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x, "Name")` instead of using `@Html.DisplayForModel("Name")`?

Comment: I just found another post with same issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678802/why-is-my-displayfor-not-looping-through-my-ienumerabledatetime. It's because I have given the template name. @Html.DisplayForModel() works fine! :)