# Print collection in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my project I have got an actionResult method returning a collection of objects like this:

```
public ActionResult PartNumberManufacturer(string id)
{
    var partNumber = Context.PartNumberTable.Where(x => x.PartNumberId == id); 
    return PartialView("PartNumberView",    partNumber);
}
```

This is my View

```
@model IEnumerable<Sales.Model.Part>
@if (Model != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.PartNumberManufacturer))
{
    @if (Model.PartNumberManufacturer == "Fr")
    {
        <div>
            <p> This product is developed in france </p>
    }
    @if (@Model.PartNumberManufacturer == "Ger")
    {
        <p> This Product is developed in Germany </p>
    }
}
```

For some reason when I run my query to search for a partnumber .. it only returns the first found partnumber in the database and it does not query for the others. So after research and research online I found that I need to return a collection and iterate each object in that collection.

How would I iterate my collection abd access each object in the collection??

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean? You want iterate the collection in your view?

Comment: actually yeah sorry thats what i meant!

Comment: Define the `@model classtype` or `@model IEnumerable<datatype>`(this case) in your view and just iterate like in common c#/VB

Comment: use a loop... show your view code, and keep it short, just include the relevant bits of what you have tried already. As it stands, this is just a "how do views work" question, which is way to broad for SO

Comment: please see edited version .. thank you

Answer (score 2):

The *proper* way, where you don't have to write the loop yourself, would be to create a DisplayTemplate for your model:

```
@model PartNumber
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.id)
```

Then you can use that DisplayTemplate in your `PartNumberView`:

```
@model IEnumerable<PartNumber>
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

[This will iterate automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651697/using-a-displaytemplate-with-displayfor-for-each-item-in-a-collection). Of course this may or may not be feasible, depending on what you want your view to look like.

Comment: this is making sense .. can it be applied to me edited verion.. please see edited version?

Comment: Either put everything from `@if (Model != null ...` in a DisplayTemplate at `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/Part.cshtml`, or put a `foreach()` in your view.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate the collection inside your view you simply can write this code inside your partial view:

```
@model IEnumerable<yourModel>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>@item.title</li>
}
```

Update: I think you need something like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Sales.Model.Part>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (Model != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.PartNumberManufacturer))
    {
        if (item.PartNumberManufacturer == "Fr")
        {
             <p> This product is developed in france </p>
        }
        else if (item.PartNumberManufacturer == "Ger")
        {
             <p> This Product is developed in Germany </p>
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @SomuchtoLearn Check the answer.