# How to use @Html.DisplayFor instead of @Html.TextBoxFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to use  `@Html.DisplayFor` instead of  `@Html.TextBoxFor` in my application.

If I use `@Html.TextBoxFor` then I can pass values to controller but if I use `@Html.DisplayFor` then it is passing null everytime.

Please suggest me how to use the same data which I am passing in Textbox should pass into DisplayFor.

```
    @for (int counter = 0; counter <= Model.Employees.Count - 1; counter++)
        {
         <tr>
           <td>
          @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Employees[counter].Name, null, new { @class = "form-control" }) do not want to use

          @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Employees[counter].Name, null, new { @class = "form-control" })   ///want to use
                </td>
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a DisplayTemplate (with DisplayFor) for each item in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651697/using-a-displaytemplate-with-displayfor-for-each-item-in-a-collection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want values to be included in the form submission, they have to be bound to a form input. This is true of any form submission, not just ASP.NET MVC.

To include values that are not editable, you would use

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.YourPropertyHere)
```

which generates a `<input type="hidden" />` element for that property.

So, your example would look something like this:

```
@for (int counter = 0; counter <= Model.Employees.Count - 1; counter++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Employees[counter].Name, null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Employees[counter].Name)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.